# How to add style to the value attribute of submitToRemote?

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, gsp

In my application i use twitter bootstrap to add nice icons to buttons etc. With normal buttons and links i can achieve this by doing..

```
<g:remoteLink .. code omitted .. class="btn">
    <i class="icon icon-warning-sign"></i> <g:message code="default.button.add.label"/>
</g:remoteLink>
```

This results in a nice button with a icon in front of the text..

Now i want to use a submitToRemote:

```
<g:submitToRemote .. code omitted .. value="${message(code: 'default.button.add.label')}" class="btn"/>
```

But i seem to fail in adding the

```
<i class="icon icon-warning-sign"></i>
```

to the value.. any hints or tips on how to achieve this?

I tried several things like putting this style in the class attribute but this also fails.

Any hints?

Comment: I think I did something similar once, have you tried using templates?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by using templates? I can create a custom taglib based on the code of submitToRemote but wondering if there is an easier solution.

Comment: You can handle your response by using a template that store your styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submitToRemote` generates an `<input type="sbumit" ... />` tag ([source code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/JavascriptTagLib.groovy#L378)), which does not easily lend itself to what you're hoping to do (`value` is expected to be a plain string, not markup).

One alternative might be to use `formRemote` instead of `submitToRemote`, along with a `<button>` that includes your icon markup:

```
<g:formRemote action="..." update="...">
   ...
   <button type="submit" ...><i class="icon icon-warning-sign"></i> Text...</button>
</g:formRemote>
```